# For loop, append new values

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

Thanks for any advice. There is my issue:

I have a list on names of companies, let's say:

`names_of_company = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'o', 'v']`

Now I want to create new list with website address where position from list with name of companies will be added into address, like below:

`links = "www.something/names/finance"`

`all_links = ["www.something/x/finance", "www.something/y/finance", "www.something/z/finance", "www.something/o/finance", "www.something/v/finance"`

I tried to use for loop but all names have been added and not only one. I will be very grateful for help

Best Regards

Comment: Is all_links your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

```
names_of_company = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'o', 'v']
new_list = list()

for i in range(len(names_of_company)):
    new_string = 'www.something/' + names_of_company[i] + '/finance'
    new_list.append(new_string)

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['www.something/x/finance', 'www.something/y/finance', 'www.something/z/finance', 'www.something/o/finance', 'www.something/v/finance']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
names = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'o', 'v']
links = ['www.something/{}/finance'.format(name) for name in names]
```